# Data abstraction and binary methods in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class, ml

I'm new to C++, and am struggling with understanding data abstraction in combination with binary methods such as equality.  I'd like to define an interface

```
class A {
 public:
  static A* Make(int);
  virtual ~A() {};
  virtual bool Eq(A*) = 0;
};
```

Using a factory pattern, I can hide the implementation:

```
class B : public A {
 public:
  B(int x) : x_(x) {}

  bool Eq(A* a) {
    return x_ == dynamic_cast<B*>(a)->x_;
  }

 private:
  int x_;
};

A* A::Make(int x) {
  return new B(x);
}
```

I can then use the abstraction:

```
A* a = A::Make(1);
A* b = A::Make(2);

if (a->Eq(b)) {
  cout << "Yes!" << endl;
} else {
  cout << "No!" << endl;
}
```

However, the dynamic cast sucks for a variety of reasons.  The biggest problem as I see it is that one can subclass A with C, and then pass an object of type C to a->Eq, which would result in undefined behavior.  I can not figure out how to define a binary method such that the code has access to the private members of both objects.  My intuition is that this can be done using a visitor pattern, but I wasn't able to come up with a solution.

For those who know ML, I essentially want to do the following:

```
module A : sig
  type t
  val make: int -> t
  val eq: t -> t -> bool
end = struct
  type t = int
  let make x = x
  let eq x y = (x = y)
end
```

Comment: The *usage* of `dynamic cast` as presented introduces UB, not the `dynamic_cast` itself. If it fails at the requested cast (such as in the A-->C derivation you described) it will return nullptr, which you never check prior to dereferencing. In other words, `dynamic_cast<>` isn't introducing undefined behavior here; *you are*.

Comment: Fair enough.  The question still stands, regardless if I do some kind of exception handling there.

Comment: I think you have a design problem with your inheritance hierarchy if it does not make sense to call Eq on a different subclasses.  Public inheritance means an 'is-a' relationship (i.e. B is-an A). So if C is-an A, and you can't call B* b; C* c; b->Eq(c), then one of the is-a relationships is not true.

Comment: @JRG  I agree I have a design problem :)  I know little of C++, so would you please propose an alternate design?  I agree that I don't need (or want) inheritance here, but it's the only thing I could think of to achieve data abstraction.  All I want is a type that admits equality with a totally hidden implementation.

Comment: @seanmcl, what you want is called the PIMPL idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can write your code using the PIMPL (pointer to implementation) idiom as follows:

In your header file (a.hpp)

```
class A
{
public:
   A(int);
   ~A();
   bool Eq(const A& a) const;

private:
   class AImpl;
   AImpl* implementation_;
};
```

In the implementation file (a.cpp)

```
struct A::AImpl {
   AImpl(int x) : x_(x) {}
   int x_;
};

A::A(int x)
   : implementation_(new AImpl(x))
{}

A::~A()
{
   delete implementation_;
}

bool
A::Eq(const A& rhs) const
{
   return implementation_->x_ == rhs.implementation_->x_;
}
```

In your main file

```
#include "a.hpp"

int main()
{
   A one(1);
   A two(2);

   return one.Eq(two);
}
```

Because all of the actual code is in the implementation file, you cannot see it from other classes (which will only include the header file a.hpp).  For clarity, I used a raw pointer, but in a real setting you would want to use an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up with a variation of this idea.  Inheritance was definitely the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to make equality functions virtual.

Here's an example:

```
class Animal
{
  public:
    virtual bool is_equal(const Animal * p_a) = 0;
};

class Human : public Animal
{
  public:
    bool is_equal(const Animal * p_a);
};

class Toad : public Animal
{
  public:
    bool is_equal(const Animal * p_a);
};
```

If I create two variables of pointers to Animals:

```
   Animal * p_animal_human = new Human;
   Animal * p_animal_toad  = new Toad;
```

The virtual `is_equal` method allows me to compare two animal classes:

```
   if (p_animal_human->is_equal(p_animal_toad)
```

This can lead to a whole bunch of run-time errors and as this example, you don't want to compare that a `Human` is equal to a `Toad`.  You may want to compare two `Human` instances or two `Toad` instances.

In the above `if` statement, only the `Animal` data, common to both classes, is compared.

Search StackOverflow for the term "[C++] slicing".

Comment: Thanks.  I upvoted this since it helped me learn something.  I ended up with something like pimpl, so I chose that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual bool Eq(const A& a) const = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    explicit B(int x) : x_(x) {}

    virtual bool Eq(const A& a) const {
        const B* b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&a);
        return b != NULL && Eq(*b);
    }
    bool Eq(const B& rhs) const { return x_ == rhs.x_; }

private:
    int x_;
};

class C : public A {
public:
    explicit C(int x) : x_(x) {}

    bool Eq(const A& a) const {
        const C* c = dynamic_cast<const C*>(&a);
        return c != NULL && Eq(*c);
    }
    bool Eq(const C& rhs) const { return x_ == rhs.x_; }

private:
    int x_;
};

int main() {
    B b1(42);
    B b2(42);
    C c(42);
    A& ab1 = b1;
    A& ab2 = b2;
    A& ac = c;

    std::cout << "ab1.Eq(ab2) = " << ab1.Eq(ab2) << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << "ab1.Eq(ac) = " << ab1.Eq(ac) << std::endl;   // false

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This kind of casting abuse indicates a design problem.

Comment: @JRG: This kind of casting abuse **may** indicate a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

- "I can not figure out how to define a binary method such that the code has access to the private members of both objects"
- In C++ you can access private member functions and protected member functions from another class or object types by using the keyword friend.
- You need to include the class that contains the private member functions or protected member functions in your header file such as;
- class A {
- friend class B;
- }
- And you can also do it the other way round. Thus class B can be a friend of class A and class A can be a friend of class B.